# Python split string with space unless a \ is in front

Tags: python, python-2.7, split, escaping

Sorry if this post is a bit confusing to read this is my first post on this site and this is a hard question to ask, I have tried my best. I have also tried googling and i can not find anything.

I am trying to make my own command line like application in python and i would like to know how to split a string if a "\" is not in front of a space and to delete the backslash.

This is what i mean.

```
>>> c = "play song I\ Want\ To\ Break\ Free"
>>> print c.split(" ")
['play', 'song', 'I\\', 'Want\\', 'To\\', 'Break\\', 'Free']
```

When I split `c` with a space it keeps the backslash however it removes the space.
This is how I want it to be like:

```
>>> c = "play song I\ Want\ To\ Break\ Free"
>>> print c.split(" ")
['play', 'song', 'I ', 'Want ', 'To ', 'Break ', 'Free']
```

If someone can help me that would be great!

Also if it needs Regular expressions could you please explain it more because I have never used them before.

**Edit**:
Now this has been solved i forgot to ask is there a way on how to detect if the backslash has been escaped or not too?

Comment: I misread at first; you *do* want to split on spaces, but when a space is preceded by a backslash, you want to preserve the space as part of the split string. *check*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like you're writing a commandline parser. If that's the case, may I recommend `shlex.split`? It properly splits a command string according to shell lexing rules, and handles escapes properly. Example:

```
>>> import shlex
>>> shlex.split('play song I\ Want\ To\ Break\ Free')
['play', 'song', 'I Want To Break Free']
```

Comment: BINGO! Exactly what I want! It even knows not to split if it's in quotes! Thanks. :) This is useful because it's going to be an input from raw_input() so if it has quotes then don't split! Thanks.

Comment: @aPyDeveloper: And I thought that you wanted to produce the demonstrated output! :-)

Comment: It has got the output I want

Answer (score 2):

Just split on the space, then replace any string ending with a backslash with with one ending in a space instead:

```
[s[:-1] + ' ' if s.endswith('\\') else s for s in c.split(' ')]
```

This is a list comprehension; `c` is split on spaces, and each resulting string is examined for a trailing `\` backslash at the end; if so, the last character is removed and a space is added.

One slight disadvantage: if the original string ends with a backslash (no space), that last backslash is also replaced by a space.

Demo:

```
>>> c = r"play song I\ Want\ To\ Break\ Free"
>>> [s[:-1] + ' ' if s.endswith('\\') else s for s in c.split(' ')]
['play', 'song', 'I ', 'Want ', 'To ', 'Break ', 'Free']
```

To handle escaped backslashes, you'd count the number of backslashes. An even number means the  backslash is escaped:

```
[s[:-1] + ' ' if s.endswith('\\') and (len(s) - len(s.rstrip('\\'))) % 2 == 1 else s
 for s in c.split(' ')]
```

Demo:

```
>>> c = r"play song I\ Want\ To\ Break\\ Free"
>>> [s[:-1] + ' ' if s.endswith('\\') and (len(s) - len(s.rstrip('\\'))) % 2 == 1 else s
...  for s in c.split(' ')]
['play', 'song', 'I ', 'Want ', 'To ', 'Break\\\\', 'Free']
```

Comment: What does this do if the string ends in a backslash?

Comment: @WilliamKunkel: the last backslash is also replaced. Hrmz.

Comment: I have also just updated my questurn if you would like to help me on it too! ;)

Comment: @aPyDeveloper: You'd have to count the number of backslashes at the end of the string; if it is even then the backslash was escaped. `len(s) - len(s.rstrip('\\'))` would tell you how many backslashes there are at the end of the string.